# Rails 4 Paperclip image not uploading - Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory @ unlink_internal - /home/app/public

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I have used paperclip to image uploading in rails.When i was uploading a image,i got a error like this **Errno::EISDIR:
Is a directory @ unlink_internal - /home/ubuntu/app/public** and this happened intermittent.Anyone give me solution.

My model file

```
class DayCare < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :logo, :default_url => 'default.png'
  # Validations
  validates_attachment :logo, content_type: { content_type: /\A(image|video)\/.*\Z/ }
end
```

My form

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name ,:id=>"registerform", url: registration_path(resource_name),html: { class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <%- if resource.errors.any? %>
    <%- f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |error_message| %>
      <%= error_message%>
    <%- end %>
  <%- end %>
  <%= f.input :email,required: true, autofocus: true,:placeholder => "Enter E-mail address",:label=>false,:input_html => { :class => "form-control" } %>
  <%= f.input :password, required: true,:placeholder => "Choose Password",:label=>false,:input_html => { :class => "form-control" } %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true,:placeholder => "Confirm Password",:label=>false,:input_html => { :class => "form-control" } %>
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :day_care, @user.build_day_care do |d| %>
    <%= d.input :name, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" },:placeholder => "Child Care Center",:label=>false %>
    <%= d.input :address, :input_html => { :class => "form-control" },:placeholder => "Street Address",:label=>false %>   
    <%= d.input :logo, as: :file ,:input_html => { :class => "form-control" },:placeholder => "",:label=>false %>
 <% end %>
 <%= f.button :submit, "Agree and Continue",:class=>"btn btn-default signup_button" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: show the form. make sure its multipart.

Comment: see above i added form

Comment: your form is not multipart, isnt it?

Comment: Sorry i can't understand what are you telling? multipart means what?

Comment: The "multipart" means you need to add ":multipart => true" to your form_for line.  But not sure what hat has to do with the error the OP reported -  which is what led me to this page- how Ruby handles finding files in folders with sub-directories in them.  Seems to fail randomly in this case, even if you have a filter to explicitly exclude sub-directories from the file-listing.
Paperclip fixed their bug, which caused this, here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1930